# get value of radio button when selected

Tags: jquery

I have below code where I have to get value of radio button when its clicked. if radio button 118 is clicked I need to get value of that radio button.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var val = $('input[type=radio].list-group-item').find(":checked").val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group" style="white-space:nowrap;">       
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <strong>Academic</strong>
  </li>    
  
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" name="Add/Enroll/Open" value="118">Add/Enroll/Open
  </li>    
 
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" name="Grades"value="119">Grades
  </li>    
 
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" name="Graduation/Diploma" value="148">Graduation/Diploma
  </li>    
 
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" name="New Student/Orientation" value="149">New 
 Student/Orientation
  </li>    
 
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" name="Proctor" value="150">Proctor
  </li>    
 
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" name="Semester Exam" value="152">Semester Exam
  </li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: "When it is clicked" should tell you that you need either a click or a change event handler.  You do not have any event handlers in your logic.

Comment: And `.list-group-item` is the parent `<li>`, no `<input>` has that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the radio button by listening for a click on the button. The demo below uses the value found in $(this).val() and places it in a div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.list-group-item > input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    $("#result").text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<UL class="list-group" style="white-space:nowrap;">
  <Li class="list-group-item"><strong>Academic</strong></Li>
  <Li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" name="Add/Enroll/Open" value="118">Add/Enroll/Open</Li>
  <Li class="list-group-item"><input type="radio" name="Grades" value="119">Grades</Li>
  <Li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" name="Graduation/Diploma" value="148">Graduation/Diploma</Li>
  <Li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" name="New Student/Orientation" value="149">New Student/Orientation
  </Li>
  <Li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" name="Proctor" value="150">Proctor</Li>
  <Li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" name="Semester Exam" value="152">Semester Exam</Li>
</UL>
<div id="result" style="background-color:coral;"></div>
```